# remove duplicate items from list if they come in certain sequence

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to remove items from the list if they appear in a certain sequence in a list

I have tried following code;

```
 a = ["abc", "def", "ijk", "lmn", "opq", "rst", "xyz"]

 b = ["ijk", "123", "456","123", "rst", "xyz" ]
 counter=0
 for i in b[:]:
      print(i)
      counter=counter+1
      print(counter)
      if i in a and i in a[counter+2]:
            print(a)
            print(">>>>>",a[counter+2])
            b.remove(i)

  print(b)
```

I am seeking following output

b = ["ijk", "123", "456","123"]

removed ["rst", "xyz"] from b because they were in back 2 back sequence in a.

Comment: What if `b=["ijk","lmn","456","123","rst","xyz"]`?

Comment: You should remove i guess if i not in a[counter+2] from what  I can understand

Comment: Why does "ijk" stay? It seems to be in both list?

Comment: @Plumb Could some items of `a` appear more than once in `a`? Could you have sequences of more than 2 items to remove?

Comment: @ScottHunter b=["456","123"]

Comment: @Sam because ijk doesn't have a sequence in a list ... if ijk and lmn then remove it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way to do it by utilizing pairs for lookups to meet the "sequence" criteria.

The idea is to construct a set of all pairs in your "a" or `lookup_list` upfront. After that, use pairs to iterate through `b`. If a pair is found, set a flag to skip two elements (the current and next one). Otherwise, append the first item since it is guaranteed it does not occur together alongside the next item in sequence.

To demonstrate:

```
from itertools import zip_longest

def remove_dupes_in_seq(lookup_list, b):
    ''' lookup_list: list from which you need to check for sequences
    b: list from which you need to get the output that 
    has all elements of b that do not occur in a sequence in lookup_list.
    '''
    pair_set_lookup = set(zip(lookup_list, lookup_list[1:]))
    #make a set of all pairs to check for sequences
    result = []
    skip_next_pair = False #boolean used to indicate that elements need to be skipped
    for pair in zip_longest(b, b[1:]):
        if skip_next_pair:
            #set the boolean according to current pair, then perform a skip
            skip_next_pair = pair in pair_set_lookup
            continue
        if pair in pair_set_lookup:
            #pair found. set flag to skip next element
            skip_next_pair = True
        else:
            #the first item is guaranteed to not occur in a sequence. Append it to output.
            result.append(pair[0])
    return result

a = ["abc", "def", "ijk", "lmn", "opq", "rst", "xyz"]
b = ["ijk", "123", "456","123", "rst", "xyz" ]
out = remove_dupes_in_seq(a, b) #['ijk', '123', '456', '123']
b2 = ["ijk","lmn","456","123","rst","xyz"]
out2 = remove_dupes_in_seq(a, b2) #['456', '123']
```

Comment: getting error: <ipython-input-40-85a2070bc453> in remove_dupes_in_seq(lookup_list, b)
      8     result = []
      9     skip_next_pair = False #boolean used to indicate that elements need to be skipped
---> 10     for pair in zip_longest(b, b[1:]):
     11         if skip_next_pair:
     12             #set the boolean according to current pair, then perform a skip

NameError: name 'zip_longest' is not defined

Comment: ---oh, i must have left out the import statement. sec--- edit: updated now.

Comment: This is great, don't want to do requirement creep on you. But if I want to find 3 words back to back sequence, all it will have to add another "IF" statement.

Comment: @PlumbInFront can you try and modify the code presented here and see if you can make it work as you want it to?

Answer (score 0):

A solution working if the items in `a` appear only once in it:

- we start by creating a dict, with items of `a` as keys and their index as value
- using `itertools.groupby`, we group the items of `b` if they appear in sequence in `a`, which corresponds to a constant value of (index in `b`) - (index in `a`).
- we keep only the sequences of length 1

So, the code:

```
from itertools import groupby, count

a = ["abc", "def", "ijk", "lmn", "opq", "rst", "xyz"]

b = ["ijk", "123", "456","123", "rst", "xyz" ]


index_in_a = {val:rank for rank, val in enumerate(a)}
index_in_b = count()

sequences = (list(group) for _, group in groupby(b, lambda item: index_in_a.get(item, -10)-next(index_in_b)))
out = [s[0] for s in sequences if len(s)==1]

print(out)
# ['ijk', '123', '456', '123']
```